# How do I have the REST API server set up on AWS EC2 use my domain name?

Tags: rest, url, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dropwizard

So say I own a domain name example.com. I have set up a REST API server using dropwizard on an AWS EC2 system. Currently, I'm accessing it as

> 127.0.0.1:8080/api/test?query=example

if say 127.0.0.1 was the ip address of the AWS EC2 system.

Now, I want to configure it such that I can call this API in following way:

> api.example.com/test?query=example

How do I go about configuring this?

Thanks.

Comment: Here are a few articles you may find useful:
(https://boxfuse.com/blog/dropwizard-aws)

(https://boxfuse.com/blog/dropwizard-aws)

Answer (score 1):

Its good to know about this tool BoxFuse.
https://boxfuse.com/getstarted/dropwizard
It will customize a linux image exactly for your Dropwizard project  .. Even more its compatible with AWS..with 10 minutes you will have your project running ..  Note its a paid service for big project!

Personally I'd prefer to custom my server as @sisyphus mentioned.. I dont like to stick with 3rd party services.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DNS entry for api.example.com which points to your EC2 instance IP address. AWS can do that for you with Route53, but you can use any DNS provider you choose.

https://aws.amazon.com/route53/

For the port forwarding you probably need to use a load balancer or a firewall configuration to redirect incoming traffic on port 80 onto your service on port 8080. If you wanted to keep it really simple you could install Apache or Nginx on your AWS instance and do the forwarding yourself. Similarly for URI rewriting.